# How is Lucene syntax with 'AND' cased wrong interpreted?

Tags: lucene

I have a query that's something like this:

`field1:"stuff" AND field2:"other"`

When it's ran with lower case `and` it produces different results.  So this query:

`field1:"stuff" and field2:"other"`

Where the 'and' is lowercase.  I'm parsing the query with the classic `QueryParser`, and it doesn't complain (throw an exception) when parsing the lower cased 'and', but it does produce 'more' results.  It's as if the 'and' might be a token that it's looking for, and so there are more results than the normal query with 2 clauses would produce?

How is Lucene syntax with 'and' cased wrong interpreted?

FYI, using Lucene 4.4 on Java 7 and Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AND` operator [must be uppercase](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Boolean_operators).  A lowercase `and` will just be interpreted to be a search term, so the resulting query will be:

```
field1:"stuff" defaultfield:and field2:"other"
```

And if you are using `StandardAnalyzer`, the term `and` will be eliminated from the search as a stop word, so your effective query is:

```
field:"stuff" field2:"other"
```

which is equivalent to combining the two with an `OR`, instead of an `AND`.